# mysql error inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
  bp.project_id,
  bp.project_name,
  bp.project_costing,
  bp.project_borrower_id,
  bp.member_userid,
  bp.project_staus,
  SUM(pb.payment_amount) as total 
FROM borrower_project_master as bp 
INNER JOIN payment_invest_master as pb ON bp.project_borrower_id=pb.payment_borrowerid
WHERE (
 (SUM(pb.payment_amount)/bp.project_costing)*100 < 100
  AND bp.project_staus='Y'
)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3
```

this query show the error Invalid use of group function. Can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: you are ussing an agg function (e.g. SUM()) but you're not grouping the resul by the other columns (e.g. project_id, project_name...)

Comment: You don't have any GROUP BY statement before ORDER BY and I think it should be better to do something like SELECT RAND() as rand ... ORDER BY rand

Answer (score 1):

Just replace JOIN table with subquery which counts sum for each `payment_borrowerid`

```
SELECT bp.project_id,bp.project_name,bp.project_costing,bp.project_borrower_id,
       bp.member_userid,bp.project_staus,pb.SUM_payment_amount as total 
    FROM  borrower_project_master as bp 
    INNER JOIN 
    ( select payment_borrowerid,SUM(payment_amount) as SUM_payment_amount
      FROM 
      payment_invest_master 
      GROUP BY  payment_borrowerid
    )
    as pb ON bp.project_borrower_id=pb.payment_borrowerid  
    WHERE (

        (pb.SUM_payment_amount/bp.project_costing)*100 < 100 
         AND bp.project_staus='Y'

        )

    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HAVING instead of WHERE.